# How to compile C++ file on Wind River Workbench 3.3 ？

Tags: vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I try to  compile C++  file  on  Wind River Workbench 3.3 , report error (etoa:4020): identifier "class" is undefined.
I have modified build tools to c++ compiler ,it still doesn't work .

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRAEA.png)

[build option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4sm6.png)

Comment: Avoid link to images in your question. Consider using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -it is a free software compiler that you could configure as a cross-compiler

Comment: Is there any details  how to configure GCC as a cross-compiler after i have installed GCC, thank you very much.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html